# how to remove GET ACCOUNTS permission from manifest in parse push?

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications

i use parse.com for push notification and use this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

i want just remove GET Accounts permission but with remove this , not work push notification .

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
```

this possible remove it . because GCM no need to this permission .

Comment: Did you find it out eventually?